# Lat Long to X Y Z position in JS .. not working

Tags: javascript

```
var phi   = (90-lat)*(Math.PI/180);
var theta = (lng+180)*(Math.PI/180);

marker_mesh.position.x = ((rad) * Math.sin(phi)*Math.cos(theta));
marker_mesh.position.z = ((rad) * Math.sin(phi)*Math.sin(theta));
marker_mesh.position.y = ((rad) * Math.cos(phi));
```

given the above my marker is not translating into the correct position on a 3D sphere ... thoughts?

It is relatively close (on the same continent) but that close :\

given below ... it should be rendering in at

**lat**: 41.7307619 **long**: -71.276195

my globe has a **boundRadius**: 500px

the current result of the function is

**x:** -119.7801015013779

**y:** 332.8157297895266

**z:** 353.3927238766871

[image]

Comment: In case someone is interested in complete coordinate transformation, please have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54039559/5437090).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your formula differs slightly from the geodetic to ECEF calculation. Refer to the formulas on Dr Math [Latitude and Longitude, GPS Conversion](https://web.archive.org/web/20181018072749/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51832.html) and Wikipedia [Geodetic to/from ECEF coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_system#Conversion_calculations). This projects the latitude, longitude to a flattened sphere (i.e. the real Earth is not perfectly spherical).

```
var cosLat = Math.cos(lat * Math.PI / 180.0);
var sinLat = Math.sin(lat * Math.PI / 180.0);
var cosLon = Math.cos(lon * Math.PI / 180.0);
var sinLon = Math.sin(lon * Math.PI / 180.0);
var rad = 6378137.0;
var f = 1.0 / 298.257224;
var C = 1.0 / Math.sqrt(cosLat * cosLat + (1 - f) * (1 - f) * sinLat * sinLat);
var S = (1.0 - f) * (1.0 - f) * C;
var h = 0.0;
marker_mesh.position.x = (rad * C + h) * cosLat * cosLon;
marker_mesh.position.y = (rad * C + h) * cosLat * sinLon;
marker_mesh.position.z = (rad * S + h) * sinLat;
```

In your scenario, because it seems you're gunning for a perfect sphere, you will need to put f = 0.0 and rad = 500.0 instead. This will cause C and S to become 1.0, so, the simplified version of the formula reduces to:

```
var cosLat = Math.cos(lat * Math.PI / 180.0);
var sinLat = Math.sin(lat * Math.PI / 180.0);
var cosLon = Math.cos(lon * Math.PI / 180.0);
var sinLon = Math.sin(lon * Math.PI / 180.0);
var rad = 500.0;
marker_mesh.position.x = rad * cosLat * cosLon;
marker_mesh.position.y = rad * cosLat * sinLon;
marker_mesh.position.z = rad * sinLat;
```

N.B. I have not validated the syntax of the Java code examples.

Comment: @samccone as requested, provided two Java snippets for you. The simplier one on the bottom may be more to your liking.

Comment: thanks for the work.... the issue is a larger one I think that relates to this.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651099/convert-long-lat-to-pixel-x-y-on-a-given-picure ...

Comment: Oh right, in that case, you may be referring to the Web Mercator projection. http://www.gal-systems.com/2011/07/convert-coordinates-between-web.html