# Convert X,Y pixel to Longitude and Latitude

Tags: javascript, math, maps, coordinates, wgs84

I have an image 8640x11520 pixels from a part of the map in real scale. I need convert my x, y point to coordinate, anyone has an idea to find out it??

[image]

```
var mapWidth = 8640;
var mapHeight = 11520;

var mapLatitudeStart = 28.349768989955244;
var mapLongitudeStart = -81.55803680419922;

var maxLatitude = 28.349806758250104;
var maxLongitude = -81.541128;

var pointNeedConversion = {'x': 4813.10 'y': 2674.84};
var pointLatitude = ??
```

Comment: is start and end latitudes the top-left and bottom-right corners, respectively?

Comment: Yes the start and end latitudes the top-left and bottom-right corners

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are mapping to lat/long, beware, you can't do that with a *linear proportion*, instead you have to check what kind of projection is applied to the map, then convert coordinates accordingly.

Usually maps are [WGS84 Projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) so you have to apply the inverse formulas for the Mercator projection.

The task is not trivial so my advice is to rely on libraries like [Proj4js](http://proj4js.org/)

The usage of the library is simple, you provide a reference system to work on, then you can trasform coordinates on another projection.

```
    // include the library
    <script src="lib/proj4js-combined.js"></script>  //adjust the path for your server
                                                     //or else use the compressed version
    // creating source and destination Proj4js objects
    // once initialized, these may be re-used as often as needed
    var source = new Proj4js.Proj('EPSG:4326');    //source coordinates will be in Longitude/Latitude, WGS84
    var dest = new Proj4js.Proj('EPSG:3785');     //destination coordinates in meters, global spherical mercators projection, see http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3785/


    // transforming point coordinates
    var p = new Proj4js.Point(-76.0,45.0);   //any object will do as long as it has 'x' and 'y' properties
    Proj4js.transform(source, dest, p);      //do the transformation.  x and y are modified in place

    //p.x and p.y are now EPSG:3785 in meters
```

Credit for the snippet: [Convert long/lat to pixel x/y on a given picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651099/convert-long-lat-to-pixel-x-y-on-a-given-picture)

**Working example:**

```js
var dest = new proj4.Proj('EPSG:4326'); //destination coordinates coordinates will be in Longitude/Latitude, WGS84 , global spherical mercators projection, see http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3785/     
var source = new proj4.Proj('EPSG:3785'); //source coordinates in meters

$("#convert").on("click", function(){
    var p = new proj4.Point($("#x").val(), $("#y").val() );
    proj4.transform(source, dest, p);
    alert("lng : " +p.x + " \nlat : " + p.y);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.3/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
x : <input type="number" id="x" />
y : <input type="number" id="y" />
<button id="convert">Convert</button>
```

**Note:** it is essential to know what is the lat/lon of the corner of your map if you intend to use it to map a GPS signal.

Here a graph example that visually explains **why** a linear proportion is not suitable:

[image]

Take a close look to (Eg) the size of the Greenland, on *mercator projection* space coordinates it looks **bigger than north America**. Of course it is not!

Comment: The mentioned EPSG: 3785 was deprecated long time ago, but then the SO question you reference is from 2010. The correct one is EPSG: 3857 , https://epsg.io/3857