# find out if long/lat within rectangle

Tags: c#, maps, coordinates, geospatial

Given a top-left long/lat and a bottom-right long/lat how can i find out if a given long/lat falls within the rectangle ?

Ideally i would be looking at something like

```
bool IsWithinArea(float topLeftLat,float topLeftLong,
   float bottomRightLat,float bottomRightLong,float testLat,float testLong)
```

**Update**

The one problem is that the rectangle created from the long/lat may be from a rotated map, so bottom right will not always be greater than top left...

Comment: Homework? This is pretty trivial...

Comment: No it is not homework, my mistake, i thought lonitude and latitude was some kind of voodoo, i didnt think it was this obvious.

Comment: Since it Lat and Lon, I assume that you want to find out if certain (lat,lon) within a certain area in the surface of the earth. If so then any of the answers given below will not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can make it more interesting than trivial checks:

```
return new Rect(topLeftLat, topLeftLong, bottomRightLat - topLeftLat, bottomRightLong - topLeftLong)
      .Contains(testLat, testLong);
```

P.S.: [Rect.Contains(...) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms558098.aspx)

Comment: nict solution! But why do you substract the topLeft Corner from the bottom right? I would construct the rect using the top left and bottom right corner and not with the top left and the lengths of the edges...

Comment: @stefanm It's a built-in .Net class, I've used constructor which was there, not my choice.

Comment: This would allocate a new Rect object every time you call your function. Watch out for memory or performance issues.

Comment: There is a static RectangleF.FromLTRB(,,,,) to avoid to calculate the width and height.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I'm thinking to simple

```
bool IsWithinArea(float topLeftLat, float topLeftLong, float bottomRightLat, float bottomRightLong, float testLat, float testLong)
{
    return (testLat >= topLeftLat && testLat <= bottomRightLat && testLong >= topLeftLong && testLong <= bottomRightLong);
}
```

Comment: That would only work if the rectangle is aligned with the x and y axes. It'd fail if the rectangle would be placed in a certain angle.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Lat is the x coordinate und Long is the y coordinate and also assuming that the coordinate systems has its origin at the left top:

```
public bool IsWithinArea(float topLeftLat,float topLeftLong,
       float bottomRightLat,float bottomRightLong,float testLat,float testLong) {

          return (testLat >= topLeftLat && testLat <= bottomRightLat && testLong >= topLeftLong && testLong <= bottomRightLong);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to normalize your long/lat pairs to simple x/y coordinates. Then it should be a simple excersize to determine if a point falls within the rectangle.

long/lat to x/y conversion can be found here: [Convert Lat/Longs to X/Y Co-ordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019997/convert-lat-longs-to-x-y-co-ordinates)