# How to overlay a floor plan onto a Map (Google Maps JavaScript API)?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm attempting to create a map of a building using the google maps javascript API. I have the actual map itself set up, but I want users to be able to view inside the building using a custom made floor plan that I would overlay on top of the building. The idea is that users can look at the map and get an easy to use view of the inside of the building. How would this be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387535/a-failed-attempt-at-placing-a-dot-over-an-image-based-on-known-lat-and-lng-point/27489153#27489153