# Google Maps Polygon to SVG Path

Tags: google-maps, math, svg, polygon, mercator

I have the coordinates that draw the following polygon in the google maps API:

[image: Polygon image]

Here is a sample of the coordinates:

```
longitude: -71.09972, latitude: 9.15553
```

Following the Mercator-projection formula from this post: [Convert a Google Maps polygon path to an SVG path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844732/convert-a-google-maps-polygon-path-to-an-svg-path?newreg=fdbf786024484cf9b3bc2085a177772a), I get a SVG path that has negative values like this:

```
M-50.559802168888886,121.46151557464762 -50.589327502222226,121.46285530595195 -50.643108835555566,121.428264939842 ...
```

When I try to draw that path, no image is shown. However, when I remove the negative symbol, show the following SVG image:

[image: SVG image]

The SVG image is flipped. Is there a way to change the formula to get the correct value? I need the SVG path clean, that means that flip the image with CSS is not an option.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: translate the path maybe transform="translate(x, y)" where you'll need to determine x & y yourself

Comment: Given your longitudes `-71` and the x formula `x:(latLng.lng+180)*(256/360)` you can't get negative x values. Can you post your code?

Comment: Post the SVG as code (intend by 4 spaces) ... see my answer to see how and check the possibility you missed the point it has

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your actual **SVG** output (in **SVG** fileformat) is hard to say where the problem is. It could be wrong coordinates conversion, wrong encoding.

1. **The most often cause of no image shown in SVG export is wrong or no viewport**

   For example this is one of my **SVG** exports (**2D** slice of glass mesh profile used as input for some machinery):

   ```
   <svg width="512" height="512" viewBox="-84.609371 -84.500872 461.177478 1568.45906" stroke-width="1.5px" stroke="black" fill="none" >
    <path stroke="blue" stroke-width="1px" d="M 285.581417 0.067317 l 6.4185 12.837 l -3.2093 1386.3928 l -0.000617 0.092881 l -288.79 -0.039845 "/>
    <path stroke="red" stroke-width="1px" d="M 285.581417 0.067317 l -38.5109 1222.7214 l -16.0462 22.4647 l -41.7202 16.0462 l -189.3453 0 "/>
   </svg>
   ```

   [image: preview]

   Take a look especially on the first line. And check if your **SVG** has it. The `viewBox` property selects which part of the space will be shown and `width,height` are the output image resolution where the `viewBox` is mapped to. You need to set booth to maintain aspect ratio.
2. **The mirror x (flip) is done quite easily see the same example again**

   ```
   <svg width="512" height="512" viewBox="-84.609371 -84.500872 461.177478 1568.45906" stroke-width="1.5px" stroke="black" fill="none" >
    <g transform="scale(-1.0,1.0) translate(+84.609371,0.0) translate(-461.177478,0.0)">
     <path stroke="blue" stroke-width="1px" d="M 285.581417 0.067317 l 6.4185 12.837 l -3.2093 1386.3928 l -0.000617 0.092881 l -288.79 -0.039845 "/>
     <path stroke="red" stroke-width="1px" d="M 285.581417 0.067317 l -38.5109 1222.7214 l -16.0462 22.4647 l -41.7202 16.0462 l -189.3453 0 "/>
    </g>
   </svg>
   ```

   [image: preview flipped]

   As you can see I added `<g>` tag with transform to flip the whole thing without changing `path` coordinates. I use `scale` and 2x `translate` (can be done with one but I wanted to show where the values comes from) You can also use `matrix` instead. The scale just inverts `x` axis and translates shift the image so it is centered again ...

**[Edit1] if you want "clean" points in path**

Then you need to apply the transform on them directly so uppercase letters (like `M,L`)  means absolute values ... so apply both scale and translation on them. Lowercase letters mean relative values so apply just scale on them and you should be fine. Another option is to apply this on the input polygon you are exporting to **SVG** instead.