# SVG Path From Polygon Longitudes and Latitudes - issue

Tags: svg

I have used the code verbatim from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844732/convert-a-google-maps-polygon-path-to-an-svg-path) to dynamically create SVG paths from Lats & Lngs and for 80% of the time it's working very nicely but I have several polygons that are not rendering correctly in SVG

I have prepared an example in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Fairport/srm7d6y6/) showing 1 that works & 1 that doesn't ...

```html
<div style="padding:20px;">
  <div>
  Top SVG = NOT Working
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="227.131 154.886 0.007 0.006">
      <path d="M227.125,154.881 227.125,154.881 227.131,154.881 227.132,154.881 227.132,154.882 227.132,154.886 227.132,154.886 227.131,154.886 227.131,154.886 227.129,154.884 227.126,154.881z"> </path>
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div>
  Bottom SVG = Working 
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="227.136 154.905 0.009 0.014">
      <path d="M227.145,154.907 227.140,154.905 227.141,154.910 227.138,154.914 227.136,154.919 227.141,154.919 227.145,154.919 227.145,154.916 227.145,154.912z M227.139,154.914 227.140,154.913 227.141,154.913 227.141,154.913 227.141,154.914 227.140,154.914 227.139,154.914z"> </path>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd appreciate it if someone could point out my issue. 
ALSO - I would like to know how and where to include a stroke color & width in this html. Thanks!!

Comment: define "not working" what do you expect to see? what do you actually see?

Comment: your viewBox should be `227.125 154.881 0.007 0.006`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a couple of problems with the first SVG:

1. The `viewBox` is incorrect. It doesn't match the shape.  It should be more like:

   ```
   viewBox="227.125 154.881 0.007 0.005"
   ```

   The first two values (minX and minY) were wrong. How did this happen? I don't know. The code in that question looks alright at first glance, but I haven't attempted to debug it.
2. Secondly, I think there is likely a floating point issue.  There are five orders of magnitude difference between the `x` and `y` offset of the shape, and its size. It seems you may be striking some floating point rounding issues, or something like that.

   If you reduce the `x` and `y` coordinates, the shape renders correctly.

```html
<div style="padding:20px;">
  <div>
  Top SVG = NOT Working
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="7.125 4.881 0.007 0.005">
      <path d="M7.125,4.881 7.125,4.881 7.131,4.881 7.132,4.881 7.132,4.882 7.132,4.886 7.132,4.886 7.131,4.886 7.131,4.886 7.129,4.884 7.126,4.881z"
            stroke="red" stroke-width=".0002"/>
    </svg>
  </div>

  <div>
  Bottom SVG = Working 
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="227.136 154.905 0.009 0.014">
      <path d="M227.145,154.907 227.140,154.905 227.141,154.910 227.138,154.914 227.136,154.919 227.141,154.919 227.145,154.919 227.145,154.916 227.145,154.912z M227.139,154.914 227.140,154.913 227.141,154.913 227.141,154.913 227.141,154.914 227.140,154.914 227.139,154.914z"> </path>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

To avoid this problem with other shapes, you could modify the code to subtract the minX and minY value from all the coordinates. After you fix issue #1, though, of course!

Comment: It was probably my trimming decimals back to 3.. That was the change I made to the original code.
And .. are you also able to assist with the stroke color and width issue. All I ever get is the entire viewBox filled with the stroke color. I've tried a few different ideas, none worked.

Comment: You can just add it to your `<path>` element.  I have updated my snippet to include a stroke on the first SVG.

Comment: I was setting the scale of the stroke-width **way** too high obviously .. as if it were a pixel width setting. Great help.

Answer (score -1):

The first `SVG` is located outside the drawing area/viewBox, however You can add the stroke inside the `<g>` tag that wraps the graphic, as in the second `SVG` theres two shapes and I added stroke to one only.

Check this code:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve">
<g stroke-width="3" stroke="#00CF00">
 <polygon points="15,81 113,9 170,172 52,189  "/>
</g>
</svg>

<br />

<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve">
<circle cx="96.3" cy="93" r="62.3"/>
<g stroke-width="3" stroke="#FFFFFF">
 <polygon  style="fill:#00CF00;" points="71.7,56 144,92 71.7,128.3 "/></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Why do you post code that has nothing to do with the question?