# What is the algorithm used in MKMapPointForCoordinate?

Tags: mapkit, mercator

What is the algorithm used in MKMapPointForCoordinate?  In other words, how does one convert a MKMapPoint to latitude/longitude and vis-versa outside of Apple's ecosystem?

Comment: Convert MKMapPoint to Latitude/Longitude and then use the formula described in this stackoverflow example, shared with this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329691/covert-latitude-longitude-point-to-a-pixels-x-y-on-mercator-projection)

Answer (score 2):

In order to convert it inside Apple system:

```
MKMapPoint yourPoint;
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = MKCoordinateForMapPoint(yourPoint);
NSLog(@"%@", location.latitude);
NSLog(@"%@", location.longitude);
```

How does Apple do it? Here you can read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH3-SW6)

Basically, it uses Mercator map projection:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MercatorProjection.html