# Move image to pre-defined x,y position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm building a custom location selector for the user, which is essentially a map (image) and a `text input` where the user enters his country. The custom map is about 1500x1000px. The final goal is to slowly auto-scroll the map to a certain pre-defined `x,y` of the selected country. How can I define, lets say, that Germany is located at 700x800, and center the map image around that point when the user selects that country from the drop down list?

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gskot27/), which includes the move-able map (I'm not adding any code in here because it is long, please excuse me and use the fiddle to browse the code)

Comment: This will depend on the map projection type. If it's mercator for example. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329691/covert-latitude-longitude-point-to-a-pixels-x-y-on-mercator-projection

Answer (score 2):

Use the Position object for this. Let's say

```
var germany = new Position(-700,-800);
```

You can set the position by using the rest of your code:

```
germany.Apply(document.getElementById('draggableElement'));
```

Although I guess that it will set the position of the top left corner and not the center, so you'd need to keep that in mind.

EDIT: Changed the numbers to negative numbers because this will actually move the picture up and left which I assume is the behaviour you want.

For presentation purposes I have added a button to your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gskot27/1/). Although this is definitely not germany ;)

EDIT2:
To animate the position change with jQuery's animate just use this syntax:

```
$('#draggableElement').animate({
    left: germany.X,
    top: germany.Y
});
```

Also see the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gskot27/8/).

Comment: You can fix that by adding half of the screens width to the `x` and half the screens height to the `y`.

Comment: That is how you center. Although in this case it would be half of the picture's dimensions and not the screen's.

Comment: Anyway we can make this transition be smooth using jQuery `Animate`?