# how to get the infotmation about the latitude and longitude for the World map image

Tags: java, javafx, dijkstra

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q58wm.gif)hello all I am trying to find  this Number

from this question :
[Convert longitude and latitude coordinates to image of a map pixels X and Y coordinates Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748832/convert-longitude-and-latitude-coordinates-to-image-of-a-map-pixels-x-and-y-coor?fbclid=IwAR3GZ8VFxHgPHd1TaMCj5XN44DBAEvPZNfCjQBUIEgawRRmdX0L6QXO8WyE)

```
 int mapWidth = 614, mapHeight = 1141;
    double mapLongitudeStart = 33.5, mapLatitudeStart = 33.5;//longitude vertical, latitude horizontal
    // length of map in long/lat
    double mapLongitude = 36.5 - mapLongitudeStart,
    // invert because it decreases as you go down
    mapLatitude = mapLatitudeStart - 29.3;
```

how can i find this number from the world map image

Comment: i need to know where he get this number and i need this number for my image 
here is my image 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q58wm.gif

Comment: Looking at your current image which is 1200 x 715 pixels and the fact that **Prime Meridian** runs longitudinally through Greenwich Park in London England (there is actually a landmark there) which is considered 0 degrees Longitude up and down the globe and the fact that the **Equator** basically runs laterally through Singapore across the globe and is considered 0 degrees latitude, this makes Prime Meridian 561 pixels from left edge of image and the Equator 461 pixels from top edge of image. If the Lat and long grid is 30 degrees then the grid is approx. 30 x 30 pixels over the globe (FLAT).

Comment: this formula give me the wrong postion in the image 

X = (Longitude + 180) * (1200 / 360) + 561
Y = (90 - Latitude) * (715 / 180) + 461

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int mapWidth = 614, mapHeight = 1141;
double mapLongitudeWidth = 36.5, mapLatitudeHeight = 29.3;
double mapLongitudeStart = 33.5, mapLatitudeStart = 33.5;//longitude vertical, latitude horizontal
// length of map in long/lat
double mapLongitude = mapLongitudeWidth - mapLongitudeStart;
// invert because it decreases as you go down
double mapLatitude = mapLatitudeStart - mapLatitudeHeight;

int xImagePos = (int) (mapWidth * (mapLongitude/mapLongitudeWidth));
int yImagePos = (int) (mapHeight * (mapLatitude/mapLatitudeHeight));

System.out.println("x: " + xImagePos + ", y: " + yImagePos);
```

It does seem odd that both  mapLongitudeStart and mapLatitudeStart are 33.5. Typo?

Comment: this exapmle i see it here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748832/convert-longitude-and-latitude-coordinates-to-image-of-a-map-pixels-x-and-y-coor?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: x: 50, y: 163 this will the out put

Comment: It does output "x: 50, y: 163". Is this incorrect?

Comment: i dont Know that is not my code 
the whole gole of the question  is to get this numbres based on my image

Comment: Where did you get the map image from? I need the lat/long of the corners and whether it is a Mercator projection.

Comment: I get the image from this web site https://geology.com/world/world-map.shtml