# Mapping Lat And Lon on a blank page

Tags: wpf, vb.net, gps

VB.net, WPF

Been researching for a while and come across nothing that is exactly what im looking for

Basically I am required to make a program that can map area covered by a machine this map can be either be a polygon covering a white screen or a polygon overlaying an offline satellite/Street map.

I have the NMEA serial GPS setup and running perfectly however I am now required to store the Lat and lon data of the machine for each second tick and then overlay this as a polygon map for area covered.

The machine width will be set by the user and map area covered with the GPS.

My Question. 
Is there a way I can overlay a gps generated coverage map on either a white screen or an offline street map?

Comment: You should probably use a map control, like [Bing Maps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750210.aspx) or [XAML Map Control](https://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to achieve here.

You can draw the coverage of your machine as a circle of `machine width` on a canvas. See [here for a tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393(v=vs.110).aspx)

When it comes to converting your lat/long to pixels for the centre of your machine you need to account for the *projection* of the chart. Lat/Long describes a location on the surface of a sphere. However your map is a flat 2d shape. To enable us to plot these points the maps are squished using a projection, the most common of which is [the mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection)

Here's an example of transforming lat / long for mercator: [Covert latitude/longitude point to a pixels (x,y) on mercator projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329691/covert-latitude-longitude-point-to-a-pixels-x-y-on-mercator-projection)