# Convert Cartesian (X,Y) to coordinates GPS (Latitude & Longitude)

Tags: java, math, maps, projection

I need to convert coordinates X, Y into Latitude and Longitude. I've read wikipedia map projections, similar stackoverflow forums, applied my custom solutions and still didn't work.

The coordinates I get from my formula are wrong, Longitude is acceptable but Latitude is not. I don't see where my calculous is wrong.

The X,Y Point is taken from a JLayeredPane with the size of a background Map image, once a smaller image is released on this Map image, [the point is taken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNHJg.png).

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {               
    DM.setUpCoordinates(layeredPane.getComponent(index-1).getLocation());       
}
```

After this, I'm trying to correctly calculate the Latitude and Longitude projection. The data I own is:

1. X,Y coordinates from the Map
2. Total width and height from the Map
3. Latitude and Longitude where the map is centered

What I have tryied so far:

Trying [Equirectangular projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection#Reverse)

```
public void setUpCoordinates(Point p) {     
    //Equirectangular projection: optimal for small streets 
    Long = ((p.getX())/(6371000*Math.cos(MG.getLati())))+MG.getLongi(); 
    Lat = (((p.getY())/6371000)+MG.getLati());
}
```

I also tryied to implement the Mercator projection from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329691/convert-latitude-longitude-point-to-a-pixels-x-y-on-mercator-projection) with very little to no success at all.

I am aware I'm not using total width and height from the Map on my formulas and this might be the error, but I don't know how to use it!

any help how to convert from (x,y) to (latitude, longitude)?

Thanks,

Comment: You didn't mention what is wrong with your approach other than "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 0):

You need to shift pixel coordinates by center position and also use map scale - longitude and latitude range (I assume that elongation `Math.cos(MG.getLati())` coefficient is accounted in longitude scale)

```
Long = (p.getX() - MapWidth/2)*LongitudeRange/MapWidth  +MG.getLongi(); 
Lat = (p.getY() - MapHeight/2)*LatitudeRange/MapHeight + MG.getLati());
```

Comment: First of all thx for answering. My Lat goes from -90 to 90 and my Long -180 to 180, but this formula is not working, let's see an example: clickedXY: (409,330) Map:(1280,700) 
central coords: lat:41.469999999999985 long:2.0699999999999985 ,solution: lat:41.470 long:2.051----------------------------

`Long = (p.getX()-MapWidth/2)*LongitudeRange/MapWidth+MG.getLongi(); ` --------------------------
**Long = (409-(1280/2))*(360/1280)+2.0699999999999985 = -62.89 =! 2.051**-----------------------

`Lat = (p.getY()-MapHeight/2)*LatitudeRange/MapHeight+MG.getLati());`
**Lat = 36.327 != 41.470**

Comment: Emm... You see all the Earth surface at the screen just now?? I think you must use real value for the degree width of visible part of map, not all 360 range.

Comment: Hi, I corrected my error and it worked, I was using the wrong Lat&Longrange as you said, thank you so much, I upvoted you but I don't have reputation so it's not visible

Comment: @Ravi Kumar Ravanam I don't understand what X and Y mean there

Comment: Your question should contain all the needed information. For now it is not clear.

Comment: What if the map is not pointed to the north? It's rotate by some angle? I don't think this will work. Right?

Comment: @Bruno Carneiro Of course, this is different problem