# formula to convert X and Y coordinates to lat and long

Tags: java, geospatial, latitude-longitude, arcgis, geopackage

I have a table called `IK_TEMP` and it contains columns called data, range .

```
        String sql = "SELECT DATA, RANGE FROM IK_TEMP";



        try (Connection conn = this.connect();

             Statement stmt  = conn.createStatement();

             ResultSet rs    = stmt.executeQuery(sql)){



            // loop through the result set

            while (rs.next()) {

                System.out.println(rs.getString("DATA") +  "\t" + 

                                   rs.getBytes("RANGE"));

               fromBytes(rs.getBytes("RANGE"));

            }
```

The RANGE field(binary / BLOB) field is already encoded using binary from arcGIS and saved in the Database.

http://www.geopackage.org/spec120/#gpb_format

I want to decode this RANGE field using java.

[Here I have tried with](https://github.com/ngageoint/geopackage-core-java/blob/master/src/main/java/mil/nga/geopackage/geom/GeoPackageGeometryData.java)  fromBytes method

```
public void fromBytes(byte[] bytes) {

            this.bytes = bytes;



            ByteReader reader = new ByteReader(bytes);



            // Get 2 bytes as the magic number and validate

            String magic = null;

            try {

                magic = reader.readString(2);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                throw new GeoPackageException(

                        "Unexpected GeoPackage Geometry magic number character encoding: Expected: "

                                + GeoPackageConstants.GEOMETRY_MAGIC_NUMBER);

            }

            if (!magic

                    .equals(GeoPackageConstants.GEOMETRY_MAGIC_NUMBER)) {

                throw new GeoPackageException(

                        "Unexpected GeoPackage Geometry magic number: "

                                + magic

                                + ", Expected: "

                                + GeoPackageConstants.GEOMETRY_MAGIC_NUMBER);

            }



            // Get a byte as the version and validate, value of 0 = version 1

            byte version = reader.readByte();

            if (version != GeoPackageConstants.GEOMETRY_VERSION_1) {

                throw new GeoPackageException(

                        "Unexpected GeoPackage Geometry version: "

                                + version

                                + ", Expected: "

                                + GeoPackageConstants.GEOMETRY_VERSION_1);

            }



            // Get a flags byte and then read the flag values

            byte flags = reader.readByte();

            int envelopeIndicator = readFlags(flags);

            reader.setByteOrder(byteOrder);



            // Read the 5th - 8th bytes as the srs id

            srsId = reader.readInt();



            // Read the envelope

            envelope = readEnvelope(envelopeIndicator, reader);



            // Save off where the WKB bytes start

            wkbGeometryIndex = reader.getNextByte();



            // Read the Well-Known Binary Geometry if not marked as empty

            if (!empty) {

                geometry = GeometryReader.readGeometry(reader);

            }



        }
```

I am getting `x` and `y` coordinates and geometryType in `geometry` object, But how can I get lat and long from this

In one of the example they have given in JS [reff](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221882/formula-to-convert-xy-to-long-lat-coordinates-given-a-point).

```
for item in (GeometryDataXYValue)!{

        let xValue = item.paths?.ofX

        let yValue = item.paths?.ofY



        //recieve x y point

        currentPoint = AGSPoint(x: xValue!, y: yValue!, spatialReference: AGSSpatialReference.webMercator()) 



        //convert to lat long by AGSSpatialReference.wgs84()



       if  let aReference = AGSGeometryEngine.projectGeometry(currentPoint!, to: AGSSpatialReference.wgs84()) as? AGSPoint {

            currentPoint = aReference

        }

    }

    var long:Double = currentPoint!.x

    var lat: Double = currentPoint!.y

    print("value long lat =  \(long , lat)")

}
```

But I want the same conversion in java.

This is another example

[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625549/generate-a-random-geopoint-from-a-fixed-distance-from-a-given-latitude-and-longi)

Comment: What are X and Y? In what units?

Comment: Does this answer your question [Convert Cartesian (X,Y) to coordinates GPS (Latitude & Longitude)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60827507/convert-cartesian-x-y-to-coordinates-gps-latitude-longitude)

Comment: Would using a 3rd party library be a bad thing? Besides that since x and y are planar coordinates while lat and long would be spherical coordinates you most likely need more data, e.g. at least the radius of the sphere you're trying to map them onto.