# Convert a long/lat on Mercator Projection with specific area and zoom to a (X,Y) point with VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, svg, maps, mercator

I'm trying to make an application that converts a `Longitude` and `Latitude` and will provide a relative point on a Mercator Projection map using `VB.NET`. However, differed from other examples, my code has to account for zooming into the SVG and also uses only a specific portion of a map.

I know that I can use this code to convert a global Mercator Projected map to a point `(X,Y)` with `VB.NET` but this example does not account for a specific area or zoom level.

This is a 'pseudocode' type example extracted from this answer on SO [(View Here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14457180/11501484).

```
latitude    = 41.145556; // (φ)
longitude   = -73.995;   // (λ)

mapWidth    = 200;
mapHeight   = 100;

// get x value
x = (longitude+180)*(mapWidth/360)

// convert from degrees to radians
latRad = latitude*PI/180;

// get y value
mercN = ln(tan((PI/4)+(latRad/2)));
y     = (mapHeight/2)-(mapWidth*mercN/(2*PI));
```

I have taken a bit of time implementing this into `VB.NET` and it works fine when given a large mercator projection of the entire world.

However, the mercator map I am using only contains a small section of the world global mercator map and is a `SVG` file. [(Download it here)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UxLOWG1wwJvHwcQndh9nn-MWOvAwialn/view?usp=sharing)

I know the map's `width` is 450 and the `height` is 530. I also know that when not zoomed at all, the map's left longitude is `123.658963` and its top latitude is `45.523885` and its right longitude is `145.820743` and its bottom latitude is `24.217586`. This information was included in the source where I downloaded the SVG map.

My map application basically renders the `SVG` map as a `bitmap` (using the svg-net library) and loads it inside a `PictureBox` while accounting for zooming by a Scale Factor.

Eventually, I would want to obtain a function that when provided a long/lat will output a relative point of the `PictureBox` where the `SVG` is rendered. This is why zooming is important.

The function pseudocode above only accounts for getting a relative (x, y) on a worldwide mercator projection and doesn't account for scaling and a specific area at all.

This code is used to render the `SVG` map with zooming (if required):

```
Dim SF As String = 1 'Zoom/Scale Factor
'Use Scrollbar to Zoom PictureBox2 which contains the loaded bitmap
 Private Sub PictureBox2_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.MouseWheel
        If e.Delta > 0 Then
            SF = SF + 0.1
            Dim svgDocument = Svg.SvgDocument.Open("C:\users\admin\Pictures\doc.svg")
            svgDocument.ShapeRendering = SvgShapeRendering.Auto
            PictureBox2.Size = New Size(CInt(650 * SF), CInt(700 * SF))
            Dim bmp As Bitmap = svgDocument.Draw(PictureBox2.Size.Width, PictureBox2.Size.Height)
            PictureBox2.Image = bmp
        Else
            SF = SF - 0.1
            Dim svgDocument = Svg.SvgDocument.Open("C:\users\admin\Pictures\doc.svg")
            svgDocument.ShapeRendering = SvgShapeRendering.Auto
            PictureBox2.Size = New Size(CInt(650 * SF), CInt(700 * SF))
            Dim bmp As Bitmap = svgDocument.Draw(PictureBox2.Size.Width, PictureBox2.Size.Height)
            PictureBox2.Image = bmp
        End If
    End Sub
```

Is there any function that could be written when supplied the longitude and latitude of a area and a zoom factor would be able to return the relative `(X,Y)` coordinates of a `SVG` map?

I've been trying to figure out this for a long time but haven't found a good result.

Comment: Why not place the pin without regard to Zoom. Lat/Lon is not changing because you zoom in.

Comment: @KevinBrown I plan to put the outputted bitmap inside a picturebox and draw graphics inside the picturebox. There are also graphics that I do not need to scale, which is why I would not want to draw them on the bitmap directly because I would still need to have a function that sizes the points. Either way requires this function